# Does std::function support a custom allocator?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator, c++14, std-function

[This open-std document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2308.html) suggests that std::function supports a custom allocator, however i can't find anything on the internet or the [usual references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) as to how to provide that custom allocator.

My research tend to make me believe that the custom allocator is implemented in `boost::function` but did not make it to `std::function` yet.

So the question is does `std::function` suuport a custom allocator in C++11 ? If no will it most likely support one in C++14 ?

Comment: @TomKnapen but now you can find the answer by googling "std::function custom allocator" :)

Comment: The question marked as a duplicate only discusses how to pass a custom allocator, but not the nuances of its support by C++ compilers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::functions` has several constructors that you can pass `std::allocator_arg` as the first argument and an actual allocator as the second.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/function

Answer (score 3):

The standard says `std::function` supports a custom allocator but some compilers (at least GCC) do not support it yet.  It's not entirely clear how custom allocators are supposed to work with `std::function`, or other class templates in the standard library that use type erasure, see e.g. [LWG 2095](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2095) and [LWG 2245](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2245). IMHO allocator support for these types is half-baked and not well specified.

[N3726](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3726.pdf) proposes some changes that would clarify how `std::function` is supposed to use its allocator, as part of some much larger changes.